# Performance Degradation After Upgrading Spark from 3.2.1 to 3.4.2

Tags: apache-spark

Hello Spark community,

We recently upgraded our Spark version from 3.2.1 to 3.4.2 and have noticed a significant increase in the processing/execution time of our jobs. The current execution times are greatly exceeding our established SLAs.

We are wondering if there might be some new configuration settings or adjustments that we need to make with this latest version to improve performance. Has anyone experienced similar issues with this upgrade? Any insights into specific Spark configurations that might help optimize our performance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you'll need to show the query plans or code samples that are slower - as it stands this question won't be possible to answer